# Método subtract de moment no funciona con toDate

Tags: javascript, nodejs, momentjs

Quiero obtener la fecha con 360 minutos de retraso.

El problema que cuando lo convierto a formato de fecha con el método `toDate()` me retorna la hora actual sin haber sustraído los 360 minutos.

```js
// creamos la fecha con 360 minutos antes
const timePast = moment().subtract(360, "minutes").format()

// fecha con 360 minutos menos con tipo string
console.log(timePast)

// imprime la fecha con tipo Date (apararece la hora exacta del momento y no resta los 360 minutos)
console.log(moment(timePast).toDate())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

> Lo que ocupo es la fecha que sea de tipo `Date` restado los 360 minutos, de antemano un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haría en 2 pasos, primero crear la fecha y luego utilizar ***moment*** para restar los 360 minutos (6 horas) a la fecha actual, algo así:

```js
var ahora = new Date()
var menos360 = moment(ahora).subtract(360, "minutes").toDate()

console.log(ahora);
console.log(menos360);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```